# Unable to minify html files using django-pipeline

Tags: django, django-views, django-pipeline

In accordance with the [django-pipeline docs](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html), I've added `'pipeline.middleware.MinifyHTMLMiddleware',` to my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  to minify html files. But, when I check the htmls that have been rendered while running the server, they are not minified. Can some one please suggest if I am missing anything.

Below are my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. I even tried with `GZipMiddleware` class enabled, but it still does'nt work. I have also tried with both `DEBUG = False` & `DEBUG = True` in settings.py with no success.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',                            
    'pipeline.middleware.MinifyHTMLMiddleware',                         

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'Testapp.signin.views.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',               

)
```

EDIT: Added Installed Apps and Static files storage settings.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'Testapp',
    'signin',

    'pipeline',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE     = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
```

Comment: Have you added `pipeline` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and set `STATICFILES_STORAGE`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I've added these settings to my question.

Comment: Does putting `pipeline.middleware.MinifyHTMLMiddleware` to the end of the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` help?

Comment: Tried that too, without success..

Answer (score 1):

To work pipeline MinifyHTMLMiddleware change DEBUG = False in settings.py

```
DEBUG = false
```

Or add in settings.py

```
PIPELINE_ENABLED = True
```

Answer (score -1):

i've had the same issue, but I've found the solution. You have to add this Middleware class first:
    `'htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware',`

When you do that it adds to request an attribute 
    `request._hit_htmlmin = True` 
which is checked then in MinifyHTMLMiddleware class. Now it's working great.

Comment: this question is about `django-pipeline` not `django-htmlmin`